# Аналог glPolygonMode в Qt5.9

Tags: qt, qt5, opengl, qtcreator

Есть ли какой-нибудь аналог `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)` и `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL)` в Qt5.9?
Я знаю, что можно подключить библиотеку OpenGL32, но хотелось бы без этого.